# React accordion get collapsible height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get height of the collapsible but it always same value which is uncollapsed div's height.

Is there a way to get actual content height of div inside the accordion ?

When I print current ref's height it always returns a fixed value. But if I click the same collapsible it returns correct value so I guess it takes uncollapsed div height of collapsible.

Accordion.js

```
    const Accordion = ({ children }) => {
    const [ selected, select ] = useState(null);
    const [ currentState, changeCurrentState ] = useState(true);

    const onCollapsibleSelected = (selectedItem, selectedState, ref) => {
        select(selectedItem);
        changeCurrentState(!selectedState);

        // Always same - because accordion is not expanded yet
        console.log(ref.current.offsetHeight)

    };

    const collapsibleChildren = children.map((item, index) => {
        let collapsible;
        if (item && item.props) {
            const hidden = selected && selected === index ? currentState : true;
            collapsible = (
                <Collapsible { ...item.props }
                    onSelect={ onCollapsibleSelected }
                    key={ index }
                    index={ index }
                    collapsed={ hidden }
                />
            );
        }

        return collapsible;
    });

    return (
        <Fragment>
            { collapsibleChildren }
        </Fragment>
    );
};

Accordion.displayName = 'Accordion';
Accordion.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any
};

export default Accordion;
```

.. index.js

```
const Collapsible = ({ content, title, onSelect, collapsed, index }) => {
    const collapsibleRef = useRef();

    const trackCollapsibleBlockClick = () => {
        const event = collapsed ? OPEN_COLLAPSIBLE_BLOCK: CLOSE_COLLAPSIBLE_BLOCK;

        trackEvent({ ... event, name: title });
    };

    const onTitleClicked = () => {
        trackCollapsibleBlockClick();
        onSelect(index, collapsed, collapsibleRef);
    };

    return (
            <CollapsibleStyle ref={ collapsibleRef } onClick={ onTitleClicked }>
                <Title collapsed={ collapsed }>{ title }</Title>
                <Content  hidden={ collapsed }>{ content }</Content>
            </CollapsibleStyle>
    );
};

Collapsible.displayName = 'Collapsible';
Collapsible.propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.array,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    onSelect: PropTypes.func,
    collapsed: PropTypes.bool,
    index: PropTypes.number
};

export default Collapsible;
```

CollapsibleStyle.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default styled.div`
    && {
        background-color: ${ ({ theme: { collapsible } }) => collapsible.backgroundColor };
        border-radius: ${ ({ theme: { collapsible } }) => collapsible.borderRadius };
        margin-bottom: ${ ({ theme: { collapsible } }) => collapsible.marginBottom };
        padding: ${ ({ theme: { collapsible } }) => collapsible.paddingVertical }
                 ${ ({ theme: { experience: { wrapper } } }) => wrapper.padding.md };
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
`;
```

I can actually see the correct height of the child when I print `ref.current.children`. But when I try to access like `ref.current.children[1].clientHeight` it returns wrong value.

[image: clientHeight]

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox?

Comment: Think we need to see `CollapsibleStyle` since that's the component you're passing the ref too.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mdcumg set your code here so we can provide a swift solution

Comment: Added CollapsibleStyle. Could not make the code run in sandboxes.

Comment: I can guess your checking the height of the collapsible item itself and not the drawer that open beneath him

Comment: I think I'm checking the correct item because when I uncollapse the item I see correct height from logs as I'm printing the ref''s height when collapsible is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as below. Using useEffect as it produces lifecycle events. I check if the collapsible item is changed by collapsed check.

```
 useEffect(() => {
                handleCollapsibleViewPort();
        }, [collapsed]);

        const handleCollapsibleViewPort = () => {
                if(uncollapsedHeight !== 0 && collapsibleRef.current.clientHeight > uncollapsedHeight ) {
                        scrollElementToTop(collapsibleRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top);
                }
        }
```

Comment: How did you get `uncollapsedHeight`?